# Python taking elements from and array and putting them into a 2d array

Tags: python

I have been trying to take elements from a array and put them into a 2d array and I was wondering if there was a way to do that?

for example

```
h = ['H', 'H', 'H', 'H', 'H', 'H', 'H', 'H', 'T']
a = Grid(3,3) #creates empty 2d array
```

output would be

```
H H H
H H H
H H T
```

I been doing something likes this.

```
for row in range(a.getHeight()):
    for col in range(a.getWidth():
        for i in range(len(h):
            a[row][col] = h[i]
```

but i get this as the output:

```
T T T
T T T
T T T
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think I might do something like this:

```
hh = iter(h)
for row in range(a.getHeight()):
    for col in range(a.getWidth()):
         a[row][col] = next(hh)
```

This assumes that you declared `a` properly.  In other words, `a` is **NOT** a list set up as follows:

```
a = [[None]*ncol]*nrow
```

That doesn't work since `a` would hold a bunch of references to *the same inner list*.  Of course, your `a` isn't a simple list since it has `getHeight` and `getWidth`, so I assume whatever type of object it has taken care of that already.

---

If you're using `numpy`, this becomes almost trivial:

```
h = np.array(['H', 'H', 'H', 'H', 'H', 'H', 'H', 'H', 'T'])
a = h.reshape((3,3))
```

Comment: My grid is set up using a class that takes in the values rows, columns and fillValue.  self._data = Array(rows)

Answer (score 2):

use a list comprehension:

```
In [11]: h = ['H', 'H', 'H', 'H', 'H', 'H', 'H', 'H', 'T']

In [12]: [h[i:i+3] for i in range(0,len(h),3)]
Out[12]: [['H', 'H', 'H'], ['H', 'H', 'H'], ['H', 'H', 'T']]
```

Comment: This won't get OP a `Grid` object which I assume is important.  If a `Grid` object isn't necessary, then I support this solution.